# How to Mount S3 Bucket on EC2 Ubuntu Server and Store Web Applications Uploads Directly in that bucket and retrive When User access that Files

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, s3fs

I Have Amazon EC2 Instance With Ubuntu 16.04 x64 and Hosted a Web Application on it.

Need to Mount S3 Bucket as one of the Folder and Need to Save User Uploaded Files Directly To S3 Bucket and Retrive When User Access That Files.

I Mounted S3 and Tried Uploading Files, But Files are not Uploading

Comment: What do the s3fs logs say?  You can get more details via -o dbglevel=info or -o dbglevel=debug.

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you're looking for: https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse

BTW network based file systems can be slow for servers, do look into it for any performance issues!

Comment: It's Helpful for mounting, But Files are not Saving in the Bucket(read-only).